# Data Comparison in database

Tags: mysql, sql

Table A has 100 cols and 500 million rows .Table B has 100 cols and 500 million rows.Best way to compare and confirm if they are identical or not.Please help with your inputs.
Thanks in advance.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For further reference you can use this: [https://dwgeek.com/quick-best-way-compare-two-tables-sql.html/#:~:text=Below%20are%20some%20of%20the%20methods%20you%20can,the%20data%20missing%20or%20changed%20in%20either%20table](https://dwgeek.com/quick-best-way-compare-two-tables-sql.html/#:%7E:text=Below%20are%20some%20of%20the%20methods%20you%20can,the%20data%20missing%20or%20changed%20in%20either%20table)

I hope this will help you to solve your question- thanks!

Comment: avoid link only answers. Try to add specific points from the link and make the answer complete. Tomorrow the url might not be working. people coming to stack overflow, should not face issues.